# How to change the default size of the Peek Definition window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I know you can resize by dragging on the top of the window, but is there a way to change the default peek definition window size to include say, 10 more lines?

Comment: Nice, I hadn't come across that Peek Definition function before. Alt+F12, this will prove very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...you actually stumbled on it yourself.

When you change the size of the peek definition window...you are essentially setting the default also.

That's how it acts across solutions in Visual Studio 2019.

[How to: View and edit code by using Peek Definition (Alt+F12)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-and-edit-code-by-using-peek-definition-alt-plus-f12?view=vs-2019)